# HttpWebRequest - получение cookies

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Есть форма логина: `localhost/login`, при переходе на нее мы получаем `PHPSSID` - сессию и записываем ее в cookies. После правильного ввода логина/пароля идет редирект на главную страницу: `localhost/home` и добавляются новые cookies: `REMEMBERME`. Такой вопрос: как мне с помощью `HttpWebRequest`, отправить данные в эту форму (залогиниться) и получить `REMEMBERME`? Делаю это так:

```
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/login");
  NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
  outgoingQueryString.Add("_username", "test");
  outgoingQueryString.Add("_password", "test");
  string postData = outgoingQueryString.ToString();

  ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
  byte[] postBytes = ascii.GetBytes(postData.ToString());


  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

  request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

  using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
    stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
  }

  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Но, в `response.Cookies` есть все, кроме нужного `REMEMBERME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из вашего кода я понятно то, что выполнив первый запрос к серверу вы получаете только ответ с редиректом, но не выполняете его.

Вы должны были получить примерно такой ответ:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2011 10:37:34 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Location: http://www.xyz.com/abc
```

затем выполнить ещё один `WebRequest` по ссылке в `Location`

Comment: Проблема в том, что я получаю код ответа 200. Сервер возвращает OK, а затем происходит редирект.

Comment: @AresGod, я так понимаю, что `javascript` сам вас перекидывает на другую страницу. Отловите запрос, который он делает, выясните что именно он сообщает серверу и у себя в коде реализуйте второй запрос, который будет передавать те же данные по роуту `localhost/home`

Comment: давайте возьмем, например, сайт `github.com`(или любой сайт). Например, как мне получить `__Host-user_session_same_site` с GitHub после авторизации? Хотелось бы увидеть пример как это сделать.

Comment: @AresGod, обратитесь по адресу: https://github.com/session

Comment: обратился, получил 1 кукис, id сессии, на этом все. Приведите пожалуйста пример, если не сложно.